# What are the purposes of Xivs?

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, paper-submission, arxiv

A colleague of mine tend to upload her researcher paper to chemrXiv just the day she submitted it to the journal.

What is exactly the purpose of that and is it always permitted?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprint

Answer (score 9):

Always permitted?  Check the journal.  Some journals may consider this "prior publication" and thus not accept the paper.  I think this is rare nowadays.

What is the purpose?  This is called "preprint".  In the Olden Days (before the Internet), a researcher would photocopy a bunch of copies of the new paper and send it to (a) other researchers in the field and (b) anyone who wrote (a postcard or letter) asking for a copy.  This was how you helped people find out about your paper!  Actual publication would only occur a year or so later.

Nowadays, you merely upload it once to the preprint server, and then everyone can get it.  Much easier.

Comment: So what is the purpose "nowadays"?

Comment: Nowadays people can see it as it is submitted, as a pre-print. It’s just easier to upload than send out a bunch of envelopes…

Comment: Paul Ginsparg's [It was twenty years ago today ...](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2700) makes for interesting reading, tracing out the early history of arXiv. One of Ginsparg's initial motivations for a central preprint server was a concern from another physicist that his disk allocation was running out due to the number of emailed articles. Another big motivation has always been to democratize access to all the preprints.

Answer (score 2):

Some definite advantages of posting on arXiv or similar preprint servers are the following.

- You get to advertise your work much earlier, and more effectively, than waiting for it to be published. (I say more effectively because many people subscribe to get daily mailings about new articles appearing in specific categories.)
- People can start citing your work, again much earlier than publication.
- You get to establish priority. If you don't bother putting up a preprint, then no-one will know what you have done, and someone else may obtain the same results independently. Even if they don't put up a preprint either, their paper may still end up getting published first.
- When you include your submitted papers in your cv, it is easier for a hiring committee to see that they are genuine (and look at them if they want).
- Your work will get indexed by Google Scholar, etc., much earlier.

As far as "always permitted" goes, there may be some rare exceptions. But for example here are overarching policies from Elsevier and Wiley.

> Please note that preprints can be shared anywhere at any time, in line with Elsevier's sharing policy. Sharing your preprints e.g. on a preprint server will not count as prior publication (see 'Multiple, redundant or concurrent publication' for more information).

> [Wiley Journal] will consider for review articles previously available as preprints. Authors may also post the submitted version of a manuscript to a preprint server at any time. Authors are requested to update any pre-publication versions with a link to the final published article.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to immediately disseminate your work as widely as possible.

As a researcher, if you want to build your reputation -- as you must if you hope to apply for jobs, get grants, earn tenure, attract grad students and collaborators, etc. -- then you want others to read your work, to cite your work, to discuss your work, to invite you to speak about your work, to ask you questions about your work.

To do this, they need to be able to access your work in the first place. Posting to a preprint server ensures that it is easily available to all.